# I want to create multidimensional Array with different random numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, random

I want to create multidimensional Array `with Random r = new Random();`

Each element should be generated randomly and they all must also be different elements. None of them should be same. Also I can not use any function.

Here is array but there are same elements. **I want to all the elements were different.**

```
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = rand.Next(1,25);
            }
        }
```

Comment: “Each element should be generated randomly but there must be all different elements” is a contradiction. Perhaps you are looking for a [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/)?

Comment: I just need if statement which will check if element is same

Comment: There are only 25 possible numbers according to your code. You could make a `List<int>` containing all 25, then shuffle the list, and then populate your array by taking one number after the other from your list.

Comment: So, whenever you create a new random element, check if it already exists, if so, generate a new one instead?

Comment: To do a shuffle, step through the array and swap values at each location with some other random location in the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Comment: @DavidRector that's *almost* a correct shuffle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors

Comment: @Blorgbeard, Why almost? It's up to the programmer to deal with random number generator bias errors; I just said "random" meaning actual random numbers.

Comment: @DavidRector sorry, that was annoyingly vague of me.  I'm not referring to RNG bias. When you iterate and swap, you need to pick a random location *after* the current position. See second para under Implementation Errors at that link.

Answer (score 1):

In the lazy version, 1D shuffled array can be copied to 2D array:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] shuffled = Enumerable.Range(1, 25).OrderBy(rand.Next).ToArray();

int[,] arr = new int[3, 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(shuffled, 0, arr, 0, arr.Length * sizeof(int));
```